# jquery ajax each file exists network error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery each and checking if file exists using ajax call. 
Please have a look of the code.

```
$(".documentLbl").each(function(){
            var actionUrl = $("input", this).val(); // url will be like - http://<<IP>>:<<PORT>>/.../fullTextURL/pdf";
            if(actionUrl != null){
                $.ajax({
                type: 'head',
                url: actionUrl,
                data: {},
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function() {
                    alert("..success..");
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (textStatus !== null) {
                        alert("error: " + textStatus);
                    } else if (errorThrown !== null) {
                        alert("exception: " + errorThrown.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert ("error");
                    }
                }
            });
            }
        });
```

I am able to access the json url when passed in browser getting json file but here getting error when using jquery ajax as: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error ...."

Please help,

Thanks in advance...

**Edited: I missed out, To make sure I am using JSON. Updated as per the request**

Comment: If network error, go to error

Comment: Are you trying to make an AJAX call to an external url? If you are, it's never going to work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Also, dataType: 'script', worked but not able to handle if the url is having some unidentified data.

Comment: the host must be an exact match aswell

Comment: You can't make an ajax request to an external url, unless you are making a request for JSONP data.

Comment: sorry, I tried with all finally only 'jsonp' left. So just tried :)

Comment: for a json call, check the reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve any of the issues, but I do not think "HEAD" is a valid option for ajax Type parameter. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) states "POST" or "GET" as valid options.

Comment: also tried with 'post' or 'get'. with dataType: script now I am getting success if valid url, but if the invalid url then not going to error block

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using error at the end of your Ajax call, try this one:

```
$("#someDivId").ajaxComplete(function(request, settings){
    if (settings.status===404){
        alert("Sad! It's not available.");
    }
});
```

Or this one:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert('page not found');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Now a better improvement to my code but always my 'settings.status' is '200'. Even if the url fails also getting '200'